# Core Data Change Data Model without Migration

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In the last Update of my App I changed the CoreData Data Modell. Unfortunately I forgot about migration and I lost the Source Code of the older Version. So I have the Challenge now to make a fix. First of all - the saved Data in CoreData isn't important, I thought about deleting the momd-File but the problem here is, the app Crashes and it needs a relaunch. Is it possible to delete the File properly and create a new one without crashing?

Here the Code how I managed to delete the momd-File. I'm doing it in the AppDelegates `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method.

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"v1.0.4"]) {

    NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL * storeURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Vocabulary" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSError * error;

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storeURL.path])
        [fileManager removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:&error];

}
```

Comment: Why aren't you deleting the .sqlite file?

Comment: What @Wain said.  If you don't care about the old data, the thing to delete is the `.sqlite` file.  Another alternative is to simply create a new `.sqlite` file with a different name, which leaves you the option of manually accessing the old data should you ever decide you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much, I'm deleting the .sqlite file now like this and it works like I wanted! Thanks to @Wain and @aroth

```
NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL * storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Vocabulary.sqlite"];
    NSError * error;
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storeURL.path])
        [fileManager removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:&error];
```